# horizontal left and right constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I don't understand how having together left and right orizontal constraints together.. I still don't understand the exact mechanism beyond interface builder, its constraints and the effective results on the simulator:
[image]

I expected the label "ingredienti" in the center of my view (like my input text above with same type of constraints).. Why does it go outside my "screen" in simulation preview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A leading or trailing constraint (which is what you've set up) sets a fixed distance between the left edge of the view and whatever you've associated it with.

The default *simulated* size for view controllers in the new universal storyboards and xib files in Xcode is 600x600.  But none of the current devices actually have this size.

So, if your label has, let's just say, 100 width, then in order to "center" it using left & right constraints using the *simulated* interface builder width of 600, we'd create a left constraint of 250 and a right constraint of 250 (250 + 100 + 250 = 600).

But again, none of the actual devices have this width.  So if we run your app on an iPhone 6, it'll have a width that translates to 375 "points".  If we run it on an iPhone 4s or iPhone 5/5s, it has a width that translates to 320 points.

So, our 100 point wide label is constraint with a constant distance of 250 points from the left edge of the parent view.  250 + 100 = 350.  But the iPhone 5 only has a width of 320 points, so part of label appears off the edge of the screen, and the right constraint is broken because the left and right constraints cannot be simultaneously satisfied (you probably have a bunch of warning messages about this in your log when you run the app).

If we want the label centered, we must create a horizontal center constraint (as [*mikle94*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32543623/2792531) demonstrates).

Comment: @volperossa The warnings would appear in the log (where `NSLog` statements show up) when you actually run the app.  From your screenshot in the question, it doesn't look like what you're looking at is the result of actually running the app.

Comment: yes, it's just in the preview screen of the assistant editor.. Aren't Warnings in NSLog the same of the IB (the warnings when I click on the yellow triangle)?

Comment: @volperossa no, not at all

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove left and right constraints from your label and then add "center-horizontally to superview" constraint.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thank you for your answer! but I don't understand why this...with left and right constraint don't I obtain same result?